# Open source lib for Audio based generative art (Flash/ActionScript )

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, audio, generative-art

I need Open source lib for Audio based generative art (Flash/Action Script)

Something like or easier than [Very Interactive People example](http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=55)

Something more strictly formatted and more 2d than [Mr.Doobs examples](http://mrdoob.com/67/PV3D_20_Audio_Visualisation_05)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Doob has the best and most detailed examples of that stuff indeed, but you can find a pretty simple and easy way of doing this with the [HYPE framework, specifically the Sound Analyzer classes](http://hype.joshuadavis.com/02_examples/soundanalyzer/01_soundanalyzer/).  Hype is a simple framework for doing all sorts of neat things in Flash and Flex and might be overkill if you want a simple sound component, but it will definitely get the job done.